# How do I initialize a WPF datagrid ItemsSource in VB code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml, datagrid

I am trying to learn additional options when using the WPF DataGrid element using Auto-Generated Columns.

The XAML is:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGrid.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="DataGrid with Autogenerated Columns" Height="350" Width="525">
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid"/>
```

I have this example to initialize the DataGrid ItemsSource in C#:

```
        public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGrid.ItemsSource = new Record[]
        {
            new Record { FirstName="first1", LastName="last1"},
            new Record { FirstName="first2", LastName="last2" }
        };
    }

    Class Record is defined in another file
```

I wanted to see this in VB, but I'm having difficulty understanding exactly what the C# code above is doing.  Is there some type of casting taking place?  My attempts to initialize the DataGrid `ItemsSource` didn't work because I couldn't figure out how to initialize the DataGrid `ItemsSource` as an `IEnumerable`.

How do I initialize the DataGrid `ItemsSource` using VB?

Comment: What you mean by _how to initialize the DataGrid as IEnumberable_? `DataGrid` is UI control and cannot be initialized as `IEnumerable`.

Comment: In `vb.net` you can do same:  `datagrid.ItemsSource = New Record() From { new Record { .FirstName="first1", .LastName="last1" }}`

Comment: I just updated my post to be a little more clear that it's the ItemsSource I'm trying to initialize.  I tried your solution.  The From keyword isn't accepted saying "Cannot initialize the type 'Record' with a collection initializer because it is not a collection type".  The editor wil accept the With keyword, but the fails at runtime because it wouldn't cast.

Comment: This was the line I tried using With:  `dataGrid.ItemsSource = New Record() With {.FirstName = "first1", .LastName = "last1"}`.  The runtime error is "Unable to cast object of type 'Ch10_ItemsControls.Record' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'."

Comment: Sorry, you need explicitly define a collection: `datagrid.ItemsSource = New List(Of Record) From { new Record With { .FirstName="first1", .LastName="last1" }}`

Comment: Thx.  I'll try your line above as well, but in the meantime the following did work. It seems I didn't see the proper placement for the outer braces.  `dataGrid.ItemsSource = {New Record() With {.FirstName = "first1", .LastName = "last1"}, New Record() With {.FirstName = "first2", .LastName = "last2"}}`

Comment: And yes, your last correction above worked as well.  Wow! Such a simple solution sometimes seems so hard to find.  Did you wish to post the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataGrid.ItemsSource` uses/accept collections for displaying data.
Seems you trying use [Collection Initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx)

As you already noticed by yourself (from the comments), you can use array initializer

```vb
datagrid.ItemsSource = 
{
    New Record With { .FirstName="first1", .LastName="last1" },
    New Record With { .FirstName="first2", .LastName="last2" }
}
```

Or you can create a list by using `From` keyword

```vb
datagrid.ItemsSource = New List(Of Record) From
{
    New Record With { .FirstName="first1", .LastName="last1" },
    New Record With { .FirstName="first2", .LastName="last2" }
}
```

Comment: That's a very important distinction and good point to clarify the focus of my problem, which was really an issue of applying a Collection Initializer.  I also will add there is an interesting difference between the 1st & 2nd method you list above.  The 1st method does not appear to allow adding rows in the DataGrid control, but the 2nd method results in a blank row at the bottom of the DataGrid allowing adds to the underlying data assuming the other DataGrid properties are set correctly.

Comment: First method will create fixed sized array with two elements. Where 2 method will create instance of the `List(Of T)` which will allow adding new elements to it.